# Laravel fetch Collection object in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in below code i have Eloquent command and that return Collection object and i can not fetch that into view.

```
$collection = DB::table('contents')
    ->join('categories', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('categories.id', '=', 'contents.category');
    })
    ->where('contents.id', '=', $id)
    ->get();
```

thats return single Collecton Object and i do not need to use `foreach`.
how to fetch this collection object in view without usign `foreach`?

i get error after using this :

```
echo $collection->title;
{{ $collection->title }}
```

ERROR:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: On the view? `{{ $collection->title }}` if you dont want to use foreach then `{{ var_dump($collection) }}`

Comment: @majimboo  i get this error:`Trying to get property of non-object` for `{{ $collection->title }}`

Comment: because that is a array of objects. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a single collection object? You must be talking about a single model? Collections are always an array of models.

Your query should be like:

```
$collection = DB::table('contents')
                ->join('categories', 'contents.category', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->where('contents.id', '=', $id)
                ->first();

echo $collection->title;
```

passing data to the view can be like:

```
$data = array(
   'collection' => $collection
);
return View::make('collection', $data);
```

accessing the data from the template:

```
{{ $collection->title }}
```